# How to find the creation date of the Google Map satellite image?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-earth, satellite-image

I am looking for a programmatic way to find the date of satellite images for any given coordinate (i.e. latitude, longitude). I have read through Google's documentation, but I have only been able to find date information for their StreetView (`google.maps.StreetViewPanoramaData.imageDate`). Nothing about date information for the satellite images.

In the Google Earth desktop application, when viewing a specific coordinate location, the image's date is presented at the bottom of the screen. So, the date is there, it is just a matter of whether or not Google makes it programmatically accessible.

Could someone suggest a way by which I can programmatically access the date of the Google Maps satellite images?

Comment: There is a infinitude of ways to do this, so I think the question is too broad as it stands

Comment: Also, if you're referring to google maps with satellite imagery and by `the date when the image has been taken` you mean the date on which the satellite created it, I doubt that data is available.

Comment: @goncalopp Google earth contain the information of the dates when the image has been taken I found this api https://developers.google.com/maps-engine/documentation/reference/v1/rasters but unable to figure out can you help me?